# What's necessary when deploying an Aurelia/Node application?

Tags: json, node.js, web-deployment, aurelia

I've have built an Aurelia application, but I'm not sure what needs to be pushed to a production server. I've read up on Node and I'm starting to grasp it a little more. If we just push the dist folder (bundled folder), index.html, and package.json, does the server automatically use the json file to pull down the appropriate packages? Or do we have to run npm install on the server's CLI to pull down those packages? If we have to do that, then I'm assuming we must do the same thing with jspm.

Also, along with the json file, do we need do push config.js to production?

**Edit**

I just ran gulp export and it produces an export folder with the following:

1. dist folder
2. jspm_packages folder
3. config.js
4. index.html
5. favicon.ico

I copy all of those files and push them into production. The first error I'm getting it a 404 on main.js

Here's my bundles.js file

```
module.exports = {
  "bundles": {
    "dist/app-build": {
      "includes": [
        "[**/*.js]",
        "**/*.html!text",
        "**/*.css!text"
      ],
      "options": {
        "inject": true,
        "minify": true,
        "depCache": true,
        "rev": false
      }
    },
    "dist/aurelia": {
      "includes": [
        "aurelia-framework",
        "aurelia-bootstrapper",
        "aurelia-fetch-client",
        "aurelia-router",
        "aurelia-animator-css",
        "aurelia-templating-binding",
        "aurelia-polyfills",
        "aurelia-templating-resources",
        "aurelia-templating-router",
        "aurelia-loader-default",
        "aurelia-history-browser",
        "aurelia-logging-console",
        "bootstrap",
        "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css!text",
        "fetch",
        "jquery"
      ],
      "options": {
        "inject": true,
        "minify": true,
        "depCache": false,
        "rev": false
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I'm confused on why it's not loading my nprogress bar. I'm getting the 404 where it's searching for appName/jspm_packages/github/rstacruz-nprogress. Why doesn't it automatically configure this to be bundled/exported? How do I fix it to where it automatically includes all of my libraries that I brought in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the command `gulp export`. It will bundle the app and copy the necessary files (index.html, config.js, etc...) to a `export` folder. Then, just copy the export folder to the server. There is no need to install packages in production.

**EDIT**

When you install a package, such as nprogress, you have to include it into one of the bundle files. The bundles are configured in the `build/bundles.js`. The aurelia navigation-skeleton comes with 2 bundles configured, one for the aurelia libraries and one for the rest of your application. You can also create more bundles if you want. To add a package into a bundle file, you just have to add its name into the specific array, for example:

```
//...
"dist/aurelia": {
      "includes": [
        "aurelia-framework",
        "aurelia-bootstrapper",
        "aurelia-fetch-client",
        "aurelia-router",
        "aurelia-animator-css",
        "aurelia-templating-binding",
        "aurelia-polyfills",
        "aurelia-templating-resources",
        "aurelia-templating-router",
        "aurelia-loader-default",
        "aurelia-history-browser",
        "aurelia-logging-console",
        "bootstrap",
        "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css!text",
        "fetch",
        "jquery",
        "nprogress"
      ],
//...
```

In the above example I am adding `nprogress` into `aurelia` bundle. You could add this into `app-build` bundle, or even create another bundle just for nprogress.

Now, when you run `gulp export`, nprogress will be bundled into aurelia-######.js file, and it will be ready to work in production.

Comment: How does that work? When you run `gulp export` does that migrate the node_modules javascript files into the folder or something? I keep having an error running the command so I can't look thru that folder at the moment

Comment: In short, `gulp bundle` will copy all node_modules/jspm_packages files that you need and merge them into one or more files. `gulp export` will run `gulp bundle` under the hood, copy some necessary files (index.html, config.js, etc.), and finally export them to a "export" folder.

Comment: Alright I got it to work...kind of. The export folder has a dist and jspm_packages folder along with a config.js and index.html file. For some reason, I'm getting 404s on my css file and a progress bar loading. The jspm_packages folder doesn't have nearly the amount of packages that I have. The only thing it's loading is twbs, bluebird, and font-awesome. What do I need to change to get it to load ALL of my packages?

Comment: It's almost like the only packages it's exporting are the ones that come with the skeleton

Comment: No no no, the jspm_packages folder inside export folder contains all the files you need. To solve your problem, you have to update the bundles.js file, inside build folder.

Comment: I just updated my question with a few more details. Could you take a look?